# export partial mysql meta data, possible?

Tags: php, mysql, backup

I want to save some specific records from a database to a file, thus:

```
"select, export etc" * from tbl1 where ClientName = 'DemoAccount';
```

should generate output

```
insert into tbl1 ...
```

Is this possible w/o any script generating the requested result?

if not, any knowledge of appropriate php-class?

:edit:

decent solution, (sql prefeered though..):

```
backup:
select * from tbl1 where ClientName='DemoAccount' into outfile '/opt/demo.sql'

restore:
delete from tbl1 where ClientName='DemoAccount';
LOAD DATA INFILE '/opt/mysql.sql' into table tbl1;
```

regards,
//t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mysqldump with the [`--where`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where) (or `-w`) option, which allows you to specify a WHERE clause.

```
mysqldump -w "ClientName = 'DemoAccount'" ...other options...
```

Comment: thanks, will evaluate this - google says it's a pig. Experiences?